# Zend Framework server requirements

Tags: php, zend-framework

My question is simple. Let's say i have setup Zend Framework on my local machine in Windows environment. What do i need to get my site live on a Unix/Linux server? Will it work only by uploading the site files and database straightaway? Do i need SSH access or something like that?

I just want to know what do we have to do to get a Zend framework site up and running on a Linux server. The documentation on official zend site documentation does not seem to be sufficient.

Any help will be highly appreciated. And btw i'm new to Zend Framework. So please bear with me.

Comment: `Will it work only by uploading the site files and database straightaway?` Try it maybe? :)

Comment: there is no specific question in relation to php or zend in this post

Comment: @emeraldjava I did not know where else to put it, was in a hurry. And i think most people would tag this post almost the same category as i did. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just upload your project. No SSH needed. You'll probably have to change your configs so that your database credentials match those of your server. If something else is wrong, like files that cannot be found, you'll be notified by an error and simply adjust your include path accordingly. You most probably won't face too many surprises!

Comment: That's exactly i was looking for. I was worried maybe it would cause problems since i am uploading a Zend Framework site for the first time. Thanks.;)